# How to register OGRLineString as boost linestring?

Tags: boost, ogr, boost-geometry

I would like to use the `boost::geometry::simplify` method with `OGRLineString`s.
While I am able to register the `OGRPoint`via the macro:

```
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D_GET_SET(OGRPoint, double, cs::cartesian, OGRPoint::getX, OGRPoint::getY, OGRPoint::setX, OGRPoint::setY)
```

I am currently not able to use the following code:

```
#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/linestring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/linestring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D_GET_SET(OGRPoint, double, cs::cartesian, OGRPoint::getX, OGRPoint::getY, OGRPoint::setX, OGRPoint::setY)
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_LINESTRING(OGRLineString)

void example()
{
  OGRLineString test;
  OGRLineString simplified;
  boost::geometry::simplify(test, simplified, 0.5);
}
```

The Simplyfy method doens't compile and I get errors stating something about  boost:mpl::eval_if_c which doesn't help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Boost.Geometry [linestring](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/concepts/concept_linestring.html) must fulfil the Boost.Range Concept. A std::vector would, for example, do. But an OGRLineString, out of the box,.

First, there should be an iterator defined, walking over the points the OGRLineString contains. Using OGRLineString::getPoint(...) this should basically be possible.

Second, if the iterator is implemented, which is probably the toughest part, OGRLineString should be adapted to Boost.Range, e.g. as described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/extending/method_2.html).

If that is done, Boost.Geometry should recognize the OGRLineString as a linestring and can read it.

However, to write into an OGRLineString, an additional step should be done. It should be a "mutable range". Because that is not (yet) defined in Boost.Range, it is until now a geometry-only thing and can be implemented by specializing three classes in the boost::geometry::traits namespace (clear, push_back and resize).

Comment: Tips: to define the iterator, use Boost.Iterator, and use iterator_facade for legacy classes that you can not change (which is the case with OGRLineString). The documentation for iterator_facade provides a good example.